# Selenium Dropdown - Element Not Visible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Good Day,

Im new to selenium python, im just trying to automate a simple form but its gives me an error at the drop-down menu saying element is not visible. Below is the site address & the code, please assist me. I've tried a couple of things including clicking it first and then using the keyboard arrow down menu, but nothing works. I believe the correct way is to just use the SELECT method but its just not working.

Website Form = **https://abx.com/become-a-member/**
( Dropdown menu  = Country & Membership)

My code used on website :

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_method")
class Testclass2():
  def test_case2(self,setup_method):
    self.driver.get("https://abx.com/")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='Become a Member']").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='abx-register-name']").send_keys("KXXXXXXna")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='abx-register-surname']").send_keys("KXXXXr")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='abx-register-email']").send_keys("thekXXXXa@gmail.com")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='abx-register-phonea']").send_keys("0123456789")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='abx-register-company']").send_keys("XYZ International")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='abx-register-website']").send_keys("www.xyzinternational.com")
    dropdown = Select(self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='abx-register-country']"))
    dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Malaysia")
```

ERROR : Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

- Tried clicking first & before selecting but failed
- Tried using keyboard arrow down buttons & enter button also failed

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT you are targeting is hidden. Some sites create this non-SELECT dropdown that looks like a dropdown and then stores the value in a hidden SELECT. Because of this, you can't interact directly with the SELECT.

For this site, you'll have to click the dropdown and then click the desired option from the dropdown. The code below will accomplish that.

For some reason the first click wasn't registering for me... I could see that the dropdown was highlighted but not actually opened. I added a second click which actually opened the dropdown and then was able to select "Malaysia". If you find that you don't need the second click, feel free to remove it. I also added waits to make sure that the dropdown and then the options were available before clicking.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
e = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "abx_register_country_chosen")))
e.click()
e.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Malaysia']"))).click()
```